# (boost) cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, boost, bjam

So, I downloaded boost_1_53_0, and ran `bjam`. After linking the "libraries" and the "includes" as per the preamble, I ran my Visual C++ solution and i get the following error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

I read some solutions about executing `bjam --build-type=complete --toolset=gcc stage`, but it seems my command prompt cannot recognize `bjam`, even though I added the `PATH` to the system variables as,

```
Variable name: bjam    
Variable Value: D:\boost_1_53_0\
```

But I still cannot get bjam running in command prompt! Thanks

Comment: If you put `b2` istead of `bjam`, does it help?

Comment: By the way, why `--toolset=gcc`? Don't you want to build boost with MSVC?

Comment: also b2 is not recognized, I'm not sure about --toolset=gcc, I found it in one of the solutions

Comment: You should run `bootstrap` first. Please refer to "Getting started" article: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Comment: Why are you trying to compile boost with gcc if you want to use it with Visual Studio?